# shorten URL with mediawiki

Tags: php, .htaccess, mediawiki

I have a mediawiki site and I try to remove `index.php` from `URL`.

So, I followed [the doc](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache) and some Stack Overflow questions, and I ended up with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

But when I try `mysite.com/some_page`, I am redirected to `mysite.com/index.phhp/my_home_page` instead of  `mysite.com/index.phhp/some_page`. Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is completely handles missing files or directories , so if user write wrong url the code will run .

Put the following code at root `.htaccess` file so no index.php will be shown at  root directory as well as sub directories :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php  /$1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: thank you but sorry it is not working. Now, when I type `mysite.com`, I get `page is not working, redirected to you too many times`

Comment: I put the `.htaccess`  file at the site's root, at the same level than `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

You replace:

```bash
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

with:

```bash
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```